# program to read and display opencv video not working properly

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I have written this video to display a video in OpenCV-2.4.2 using CodeBlocks. So far the file compiles fine but the video doesn't seem to be playing and the showing plus the display window is so small, all I see are the minimize, maximize and close buttons.
Below is my code can anyone be of help? Thanks.

```
     using namespace cv;
     using namespace std;

     void info()
     {
         cout << "This program will accept input video with fixed lengths and produce video textures" << endl;
     }

     int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {
         info();
         if(argc != 2)
         {
            cout << "Please enter more parameters" << endl;
            return -1;

         }

         const string source = argv[1];
         VideoCapture input_vid(source);
         if(! input_vid.isOpened())
         {
           cout << "Error: Could not find input video file" << source << endl;
           return -1;
         }

         const char* PLAY = "Video player";

         namedWindow(PLAY, 0);
         setWindowProperty(PLAY, CV_WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE,CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

         for(;;)
         {
           Mat frame;
           input_vid >> frame;
         }

          return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to push the frame to the window

```
imshow(PLAY, frame);
```

Comment: also `waitKey(msec);`, where msec is your desired framerate.  Without that, imshow does nothing.

Comment: Done all that but I still have the problem where the frame is so small I can't tell if the video is playing or not. I thought CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE, does that already?

Comment: Sorted the problem now. Cheers!